# Is there a set of C# data readonly generic collections / data structures?

Tags: c#, collections, f#

I'm looking for a library of read-only generic collections that are a mirror (or rather implement or extend) the .NET versions of the common `System.Collections.Generic;` collections compatible with .NET v3.5.

I would guess that F# probably has a number readonly collections (but I'm not sure if they implement the interfaces from System.Collections.Generic).  Beyond that I'd rather not install F# on servers. I guess I might be able to simply deploy the F# dll(s), if that's doable, which I suspect it is.

Is there a library of read-only generic collection classes that implement the interfaces in System.Collections.Generic and provide the same performance (or better) characteristics?  For instance, random access array backed implementation of IList (only read-only).

Comment: Read-Only interfaces to most of the collections in that namespace were added in 4.5.  The collection won't be immutable, but you can provide a read-only view to others.  If the collection is *only* exposed through such a view it is effectively immutable; for all intents and purposes.

Comment: You can deploy the F# assemblies like any other -- so if you want to use the immutable collection types in `FSharp.Core` from your C# app, just add a reference to it and mark it as 'Copy Local'.

Comment: Most of the methods defined in the existing System.Collections.Generic interfaces are useless for immutable collections.  For example, from the `IList<T>` interface, you can't implement set_Item, Add, Clear, Insert, Remove, or RemoveAt.  Implementing these interfaces on immutable collections would perhaps be a convenience in some situations, but would be asking for thrown exceptions in most cases.  For this reason, the only System.Collections.Generic interface that the F# collections implement is `IEnumerable<T>`

Answer (score 6):

If you want *immutable*, not just read-only, collections you might be interested in [Microsoft's preview of immutable collections](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2012/12/18/preview-of-immutable-collections-released-on-nuget.aspx).

There are counterparts for most of the classes in `System.Collections.Generic`.

Comment: Looked promising, but appears only for .NET 4.5

Answer (score 3):

The [`ReadOnlyCollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms132474%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) in `System.Collections.ObjectModel`

It is a wrapper on any collection you want.
The most common is to use a `List<T>` and wrap it with the `ReadOnlyCollection<T>`.

Then, in the public implementation, you only give access to `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` and set `List<T>` as private.

```
public class MyClass
{
    private List<MyItemClass> list;
    public ReadOnlyCollection<MyItemClass> MyReadOnlyCollection { get; private set; }

    public MyClass()
    {
        list = new List<MyItemClass>() { ... };
        MyReadOnlyCollection = new ReadOnlyCollection<MyItemClass>(list);
    }
}
```

If you want an "immutable object":

```
public class MyClass
{
    public ReadOnlyCollection<MyItemClass> MyReadOnlyCollection { get; private set; }

    public MyClass()
    {
        List<MyItemClass> list = new List<MyItemClass>() { ... };
        MyReadOnlyCollection = new ReadOnlyCollection<MyItemClass>(list);
    }
}
```

This way, the state of `MyReadOnlyCollection` and of `list` will not be changed.

Comment: I've seen that collection -- I'm interested in ISet, IDictionary, IList, etc.  I was hoping for a single source for each of these structures instead of ICollection from ObjectModel, and IList / ISet from somewhere else.  It also appears that ReadOnlyCollection<T> is only a wrapper.  If the original reference is modified ReadOnlyCollection is modified.  I guess, my original intent was off -- by read-only I meant immutable.

Comment: @lucidquiet Yes but you can remove the visible references to the underlying collection. Then, you won't be able to access it afterward.

Comment: @lucidquiet: You're asking for conflicting things. `ISet`, `IDictionary`, and `IList` are mutable interfaces, so you won't find immutable collections that implement these unless they throw exceptions for mutable ops. In fact, that's what F#'s [`dict`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353774.aspx) operator does.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at System.Collection.ObjectModel.

There you got a read-only dictionary, list and observable list.

They play nice with anything enumerable.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your requirements,  it might be sufficient to expose the collection as `IEnumerable<T>`, which is read-only by nature:

```
var list = new List<int> {1,2,3,4};
var coll = list.AsEnumerable(); //read-only interface
```

However, the caller could still cast the collection to the concrete type to make it mutable:

```
var backToList = (List<int>)coll; //now it's mutable again
```

You also have the option to use a `ReadOnlyCollection<T>`, which doesn't have the problem above:

```
var readonlyCollection = list.AsReadOnly(); // returns a ReadOnlyCollection<int>
```